# Obtener una fecha a partir de una cadena de texto con javascript

Tags: javascript, string, regex, bucles

A partir de una cadena de mensaje estoy buscando obtener una fecha en formato AAAA-MM-DD, estoy usando expresiones regulares para filtrar en la cadena de texto, y un ciclo while, pero solo puedo llegar hasta allí :c.
Agradezco su guía colegas.

```
const str = "HGI_YEAR2019testmonth12DATE12ABU1234DAY23"

let regex = /year(?<year>\d{4})|month(?<month>\d{1,2})|day(?<day>\d{1,2})/gm;

let x;

let date = ''

while((x = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if(x.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
}
```

De el ejemplo del código la salida debería ser: 2019-12-23

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular donde hace `match` a los números que deseas tener, en este caso al número que va al lado de las letras `year` (2019), `month` (12) y `day` (23) que están en tu cadena, ya sea mayúscula o minúscula:

```
let anioRegex = /year(\d{4})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "year" en la cadena.
let mesRegex = /month(\d{2})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "month" en la cadena.
let diaRegex = /day(\d{2})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "day" en la cadena.
```

Veamos cómo funciona:

```js
function dateFormat(string) {
  newString = string.toLowerCase(); // convertimos la cadena en minúscula, ya que el match buscará a los números que están al lado de tal palabra en minúscula.

  let anioRegex = /year(\d{4})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "year" en la cadena.
  let mesRegex = /month(\d{2})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "month" en la cadena.
  let diaRegex = /day(\d{2})/; // buscamos los números que están al lado de la palabra "day" en la cadena.

  let anio = anioRegex.exec(newString)[1]; // devuelve un array => ["year1970", "1970"], entonces entramos a la posición "1" => "1970".
  let mes = mesRegex.exec(newString)[1]; // devuelve un array => ["month02", "02"], entonces entramos a la posición "1" => "02".
  let dia = diaRegex.exec(newString)[1]; // devuelve un array => ["day29", "29"], entonces entramos a la posición "1" => "29".

  return `${anio}-${mes}-${dia}`; // juntamos los resultados con el formato esperado.
}

console.log(dateFormat('P_6VLUyear1970UUw3}=tjgHmonth02Pj{yVQB[Uday29'));
console.log(dateFormat('HGI_YEAR2019testmonth12DATE12ABU1234DAY23'));
console.log(dateFormat('382_year2021}=#~testmonth12:@DATE03ABU1234_@lsday14'));
```

Comment: Cunado cambio la cadena de texto ya no funciona, por ejemplo si pruebo con esta "P_6VLUyear1970UUw3}=tjgHmonth02Pj{yVQB[Uday29" ya no da.

Comment: Nunca especificaste si las letras que contiene tu string van a variar, en este caso tendrías que cambiar las letras que van antes de cada número en el regex.

Comment: @AngelVera las letras que van antes de cada número en tu string son aleatorias??

Comment: Las cadenas de palabras son aleatoreas. Solo como referencia tenemos la palabra year, month y day antes de cada número,  eso siempre estará ahí y sirve de referencia para saber cual es fecha y no confundir con algún otro numero que puede aparecer en la cadena, todo lo demás de la cadena es cambiante.

Comment: @AngelVera modifiqué mi respuesta usando un regex más óptimo, ahora ya funcionaría para cualquiera de los casos, me avisas si ahora te sirve.

Comment: ChatGPT ? :V, ya encontré la solución xd, gracias

Comment: @AngelVera No, para nada, es un regex muy básico, capaz el bot acierte, o lo diga de otra forma.